# C# : What should I use: Array or ArrayList or List of list?

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, list

i'm learning C# and i need some advise.

I'm trying to create users (Active Directory) from an XML file. Those users are students and teachers. For each user i need his **name**, **surname**, **birthdate** to generate his **login**, **password**.

- A student can be only member of one groupe (his class).
- A teacher can have one or more group (classes where he teaches).

All information i need are in the XML.

In powershell, it works like this :

- Students : `tab[name,surname,birthdate,login,group]` (and works also in
  c#)
- Teachers : `tab[name,surname,birthdate,login,tab[groups]]`

How can i do this in C# ? I try with an Array in 3D but it his ugly and not very performant with hundreds of users ...
Is there a better way to do this with lists ? ArrayList ?

Sorry for ma bad english ...

Thanks for your help (and pieces of code ^^) !

Example of the XML for the teachers :

```
<DATA>
-<PERSONS>
--<PERSON ID="6022">
---<NAME>DOE</NAME>
---<SURNAME>John</SURNAME>
---<BIRHDATE>1952-06-29</DATE_NAISSANCE>
--</PERSON>
--...
-</PERSONS>
-<CLASSES>
--<CLASS CODE="3A">
---<TEACHERS>
----<TEACHER ID="6022">
-----<SUBJECT>Maths</SUBJECT>
----</TEACHER>
---</TEACHERS>
--</CLASS>
--<CLASS CODE="5D">
---<TEACHERS>
----<TEACHER ID="6022">
-----<SUBJECT>Maths</SUBJECT>
----</TEACHER>
---</TEACHERS>
--</CLASS>
...
-</CLASSES>
</DATA>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

You can create one by calling `XDocument.Parse("<myDoc></myDoc>")`

**Example:**

```
var xml = @"<DATA>
<PERSONS>
<PERSON ID=""6022"">
<NAME>DOE</NAME>
<SURNAME>John</SURNAME>
<BIRHDATE>19520629</BIRHDATE>
</PERSON>
</PERSONS>
<CLASSES>
<CLASS CODE=""3A"">
<TEACHERS>
<TEACHER ID=""6022"">
<SUBJECT>Maths</SUBJECT>
</TEACHER>
</TEACHERS>
</CLASS>
<CLASS CODE=""5D"">
<TEACHERS>
<TEACHER ID=""6022"">
<SUBJECT>Maths</SUBJECT>
</TEACHER>
</TEACHERS>
</CLASS>
</CLASSES>
</DATA>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var peopleElements = doc
    .Elements("DATA")
    .Elements("PERSONS")
    .Elements("PERSON");
var q = from person in peopleElements
select new {
    Name = person.Element("NAME").Value,
    BirthDate = person.Element("BIRHDATE").Value
};

var peopleList = q.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to have them under arrays or lists because i compare users to active directory to create/modify them (each year for each school).... Actually i use XmlDocument and XmlNode to have attributes values and Nodes InnerText for m array. Do you suggest me to work directly from the xml files ?

Comment: No. I wouldn't parse the files myself. I've used XmlDocument in the past as well. It's just a bit more difficult to use. XDocument is newer and a bit easier to use in my opinion.

Comment: @BrandonCuff nice answer but you might want to mention that this is a LinqPad sample or remove the `Dump()`

Comment: Removed `Dump()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for: what are you doing right now with an Array that you want to change? Are you talking about each person just being a glob of strings in an array? Given what you stated, you should really make a Person class with the properties shared by both students and teachers, then two more classes, Student and Teacher, both inheriting from that class. At that point, it would make sense to have, rather than a single Group property, a Class string property on Student, and a ClassesTaught List< string > property on Teacher. 3d arrays are great for things that are best represented as a 3d array (points in 3d space, for instance), but for lists of *organized* data, you would be best served actually organizing your data into classes with properties.

At that point you would parse all your data into individual Person objects, and add them into a List < Person >. (Or, if you preferred, depending on what you were doing with it, possibly a Dictionary < int, Person >, if that ID property is actually a unique identifier, and you wanted easy access to your Person objects by that id key.)

Comment: All that i want to do, is creating users and affecting them to their group(s). I need to verify if users exists already and update them if needed. Actually in powershell i create and array for students and teachers with the XML files, i create and array for students and teachers with the existing users, then i compare them and do the job. In powershell i can have and array with one element which is an array to (for the groups of each teacher) but i can't do it with c# (i don't know how)

Comment: Right, and that is what I suggest, creating a list of Users, with properties. Or are you saying you don't care about any of their other properties, all you care about is the set of users, and that each user has one or more groups? Do you care whether a user in your list is a student or a teacher? I'm not quite sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I think that my problem is my misunderstanding of c# and classes (actually i'm using it like function in VB). I need to find how to temporarly store values of each users (teachers and student separatly) from xml. With thoses values i create/update each users. Previously, i use arrays in powershell (the teacher array had a array for the group element). I don't know ho to do it in c# so i try with a 3D array but it is not very good...

Answer (score 0):

There really aren't many use cases for ArrayList any more.  Avoiding it and its constant companion of casting and re-casting if you can help it.